# JavaScript Object get value for property in sub objects

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object.

```
{
  ...
  a: 12,
  ...
}
```

Second object.

```
{
  ...
  subOjb: {
     a: 53
  },
  ...
}
```

Third object.

```
{
  ...
  subOjb: {
     subSub: {
        a: 32
     }
  },
  ...
}
```

Let's say I am interested in finding the value of property `a` regardless of how deeply it is nested. Is there a library to get the value of property no matter how deeply it is nested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to exploit `JSON.stringify`, which will recursively iterate over all properties, no library needed:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  outer: [
    'item',
    {
      inner: {
        prop: 'prop',
        another: {
          a: 'theValueOfA'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

let a;
JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => {
  if (key === 'a') a = val;
  return val;
});
console.log(a);
```

Another option, write your own recursive function that iterates over the `entries` of objects:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'foo',
  outer: [
    'item',
    {
      inner: {
        prop: 'prop',
        another: {
          a: 'theValueOfA'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

const findProp = (obj, prop) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
  if (a) return a;
  if (key === prop) return val;
  if (typeof val === 'object') return findProp(val, prop);
}, null);
console.log(findProp(obj, 'a'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are looking for first occurrence of `a`. In this case you basically want to do Breadth-first search ([Wikipedia article on BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)).

```
const obj = {
    subObj1: {
        subSub1: {
            a: 32
        },
        subSub2: {
            a: 35
        }
    },
    subObj2: {}
};

function bfs(root, attr) {
    const q = [root];

    while (q.length) {
        const node = q.shift();

        for (let item in node) {
            if (node[attr] !== undefined) return node[attr];
            if (node[item] instanceof Object) q.push(node[item]);
        }  
    }
}

bfs(obj, 'a') // 32
bfs({}, 'a') // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

## Nested Objects

This function isn't as slick as [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52241897/2813224) the path to
the targeted key needs to be known.

> ```
> /* @ Function:
>  *  getObj(object, array)
>  */
> /* @ Params:
>  * object [Object]: Plain Object (can have nested properties)
>  * array [Array of Strings]: The elements comprise of a path that ends at the 
>  * target key.
>  *
>  * Example: 
>  * var object = {
>  *   prop0: 'string0',
>  *   obj0: {
>  *     array0: [{
>  *       key0: 'value0'
>  *     }, {
>  *         key1: 'value1'
>  *       }]
>  *   },
>  *   prop1: 'string1',
>  *   prop2: 'string2'
>  * };
>  * Target key: 'key0'
>  * array = ['obj0', 'array0', 0, 'key0']
>  * Any arrays that are included in path needs an index number if its contents 
>  * are included in the path as well.
>  */
> ```

**Details:** [HackerNoon - Accessing Nested Objects in JavaScript](https://hackernoon.com/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript-f02f1bd6387f#2934)

**MDN Article:** [Array.prototype.reduce(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

---

### Demo

```js
const obj = {
  prop0: 'string0',
  prop1: 'string1',
  array0: [{
    key0: 'value0',
    key1: 'value1'
  }, {
    key2: 'value2', //..............['array0', 1, 'key2']
    key3: 'value3'
  }],
  obj0: {
    subProp0: 'subString0',
    subProp1: 'subString1',
    subObj0: { //...................['obj0', 'subObj0']
      lowerProp0: 'lowerString0' //.['obj0', 'subObj0', 'lowerProp0']
    }
  }
};



const getObj = (object, array) =>
  array.reduce((acc, cur) =>
    (acc && acc[cur] !== 'undefined') ? acc[cur] : undefined, object);

const result0 = getObj(obj, ['obj0', 'subObj0', 'lowerProp0']);
const result1 = getObj(obj, ['obj0', 'subObj0']);
const result2 = getObj(obj, ['array0', 1, 'key2']);

console.log(result0);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```